# Need to find a spare accessory for a Dell PowerEdge 1850

Tags: dell-poweredge, accessories

I am searching (*urgently*) for an accessory whose name I do not know.

I was trying to unplug a patch cable from one of the in-built NICs which has a clever little tool positioned above it. It has a blue spring-loaded piece of plastic on it that you push in (towards the server) and it unplugs the clip from the port. It's a simple and really useful thing seeing as there is a piece of metal above it.

The issue is that I'd never used one of those things and I've stupidly managed to snap off the thing from the server and it's too badly broken to fix unless I spend hours on end holding it with super-glue [other glues are available].

What is this thing called and how could I purchase a replacement part?

Thanks,

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Have you considered contacting Dell?

Comment: Yes, I can understand this. But this is kinda urgent. And no, good thought

Comment: I bet you could find a seller on eBay that would be willing to part with one.

Answer (score 3):

Admit to your boss you made a mistake. Tell him you'll deal with it by calling Dell and that you'll pay out of pocket if need be, chances are this little game you're playing will get you in more trouble than just simply admitting you didn't know what you were doing and broke it on accident.

Comment: Probably the best idea.  Dell will have replacement parts for their stuff.